# Unexpected token after upgrade to Angular 16

Tags: angular

I upgraded my Angular webapp from v14 to v16. After applying some manual modifications to the source code I deployed the application to my server, but when I open it in Google Chrome I see a white page and the following error in the JS console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
```

This error comes from the main JS file of the application. When I open the generated file and search for "??=" I find several places, e.g.

```
e.contentHooks??=[]
```

Everything works fine when I run the application with `ng serve` locally.
Any ideas what might be the problem?

Cheers,
Ralf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be related to an old Chrome version. After upgrading to the newest version everything works fine.